# Iframe hover not working in IE (all versions)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, iframe

I have problem with iframe:hover. My iframe is hidden, and when I onmouse on link or iframe, then the iframe is visible. This works fine in every browser except IE (all versions). I've tried many solutions, but it still doesn't work.

[link with live example of my problem](http://durian.newlogic.cz) - element "MedicalTourism Rewievs" right from contact form.

Have you any idea?

EDIT: [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3zLK5/)

```
<div id="wbw">
    <a class="wh"></a>
    <div id="ta_widget_box"></div>
    <script language="Javascript" src="http://reviews.treatmentabroad.com/js/widget.js"></script>
    <script language="Javascript">init_widget_rnr('278237/es','ta_widget_box');</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Would be easier to see what the problem was if you made a mock up in JSFiddle (or similar). We don't need to see the whole page.

Comment: Did you tried to lay an DIV-Container over the iFrame, with same click-event and your hover-event? Beware, in IE a empty DIV element (without background) has it's hover-event only over the border. So place an non existing background (or spacer.gif) with CSS. Place the container with position:absolute and z-index:{bigger than iframe}...

Comment: Yes, I tried place conteiner with bigger z-index via css, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with this selector, it's not working in IE7/IE8:

```
#wbw a.wh:hover + #ta_widget_box {
    display: block;
}
```

So I suggest a javascript solution, a very basic example:

http://jsfiddle.net/3zLK5/9/

I've tested it in IE7/IE8/IE9 and it works!

Comment: I am not agreed with your answer, that is problem with selector (because in IE9/10 this doesn't work too). I think, thats problem with hover on iframe, but don't know what. 

But your js soulution works fine to me, so i thank you :)

Comment: You welcome :) Let me explain, this selector should work, but in this particular case, the selector seems buggy, I don't know exactly why, but I guess it's because there is an iframe inside a hidden div, ie7/ie8 in my tests doesn't render properly a hidden iframe than it's displayed by an adjacent sibling selector rule, but the jsfiddle code you wrote works (at least in my computer) in IE9.

Comment: Thanks for answer, now I'm smarter :)