# hover state disappears in ie8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, hover

I have a bit of a IE8 problem (sound familiar?)

I have a button. when you hover over the button the hover state produces a larger box that has html inside. in this particular case, it's a small music player.

so it goes like this, when you hover over the button it produces a small music player with clickable links and some text. you can move your mouse anywhere inside this box, but as soon as you leave the box/music player, the hover state goes away again.
sorry but I don't know how else to explain it.

this all works a treat except for IE8.

in IE8, the hover state disappears as soon as the mouse leaves the original small button. so navigating around the music player becomes impossible.

now I have noticed that when there is no html in the hover box, it works fine, but when there is html (in this case an iframe) it loses the hover as soon as I touch any html inside the hovering box. so it looks like the problem is not the hover box, but the code inside the box that makes it lose focus

what I would like to know is, is this a known issue in IE8, or could it just be bad coding from my side. in which case i can post the css.

Comment: Read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pietbez/b9Z5G/

Answer (score 1):

I've had problems with :HOVER states in IE8 too and I noticed that the same CSS (even pointing to the same external CSS file) worked on some pages but not others. The solution for me was to consistently add a DOCTYPE to the top of all pages (above the starting HTML tag).

It seems obvious now, but sometimes (especially when editing old sites) the DOCTYPE is not always specified.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem doesn't seem to lie in hover itself. Firstly you assume some window height and your project just look weird if the height is different. Assuming you did some very exact calculations on such assumptions your problem is probably the box model problem. `box-sizing:border-box` might help, but you would have to recalculate everything.

Also you can use timeout before the elements gets hidden/drop down so that micro mouse movements don't shake elements and maybe allow to "catch" them.

Having both things in mind all hovering problems should be fixable.

EDIT: For iframe hover have a look at: [Iframe hover not working in IE (all versions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948523/iframe-hover-not-working-in-ie-all-versions).

Comment: ok sorry for my newbe approach to this, still learning, diodeus, i understan compleatly, i have now put the code on js fiddle.  nux, thanks for that. i will check that out. it is also very hard for me to test on IE8 because im on mac and vertualbox brings my machine to its knees

Comment: ok, so this is where i get realy stupid.. the timeout, is that set in JS or css?

Comment: Oh, iframe. Then I think it won't work without JavaScript. I've added a link to similar question.

Comment: thanks Nux, i have been sitting on this thing for the last 4 days, this solves my problem. however (isnt there always) now my little player works. on hover, player apears, move away, player goes away. but the moment i play any of the song in the player, the hover state wont hide when you move the mouse away. pause the song and it works again. this is a problem as i need the player to play in the background and only reapear when the user calls it again to change a track. once again, only IE problem. cant all web developers join hands to form a boycott movement against IE !!